# Test flex mobile application built with 4.10 sdk with testcomplete

Tags: ui-automation, functional-testing, automated-tests, testcomplete, flex4.10

I've been able to test a flex desktop app after following this steps ( http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/30904/#Compile ) but now I have to test a mobile flex app and I always get this error when I'm starting the simulator, and after the error the app does not run:

```
SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature.
at flash.system::Security$/allowDomain()
at FlexClient::Agent()
at FlexClient::Agent$/init()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::kickOff()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlex4.10/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/managers/SystemManager.as:2823]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::preloader_completeHandler()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlex4.10/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/managers/SystemManager.as:2731]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlex4.10/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/preloaders/Preloader.as:572]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

I remember this error when I tested the desktop app but, somehow, I finally got around it, but nothing seems to work with this mobile app...

Its a flex app built with sdk 4.10 and running on the air simulator for iphone 3gs.

Hope you can help me...

Comment: The problem seems to be quite technical. I think that you need to contact the SmartBear support: http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete

Comment: Already did that, my support question was escalated to the level 2 support representative.